# Jersey Rest Get with special character

Tags: java, rest, jersey

How do I create a GET rest method that accept "@" sign parameter?
Currently it doesn't like this because of the @ sign.
I am passing in /resource/user/my@email.com/password

```
@Path("/user/{Email}/{Password}")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public JResponse<DtoUser> ValidateUser(@PathParam("Email") String email,@PathParam("Password") String password) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Validating user {0}", email);
    IUserRepository repo =  new UserRepository();
    return JResponse.ok(repo.ValidateUser(email, password)).build();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301004/229087). Seems that you could encode your '@' with '%40' in your call.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to encode the values that are going to be added to the string.  for example the @ symbol is converted to %40.

`URLEncoder.encode(string,"UTF-8");`
would encode the string to

```
/resource/user/my%40email.com/password
```

more information of this can be found in the javadocs of the jdk
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Please read this before using the URLEncoder class:
http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/02/uri-escaping-and-javaneturlencoder

A good alternative is Google's PercentEscaper:
http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0.0-alpha/javadoc/com/google/api/data/client/v2/escape/PercentEscaper.html