# Jersey 1.9 @Path with slashes

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have the regrettable task of trying to pass slashes in url parameters(legacy app).

I've read this answer on how to solve this in 2.0+ : [JAX-RS @PathParam How to pass a String with slashes, hyphens & equals too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291428/jax-rs-pathparam-how-to-pass-a-string-with-slashes-hyphens-equals-too)

However the following solution will not work in 1.9:
@Path("{id}/{emailAddress : (.+)?}")

Test path: 5/emailpart1/part2@example.org

This returns a 404 saying it cannot find a route to match.

FYI, this is getting sent over URL-encoded, but our container(Tomcat) automatically decodes this before it gets handled by Jersey.

Edit: Turns out the entire request was getting blocked by Apache's `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive. 
Relevant: [Need to allow encoded slashes on Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache)

Comment: That `@Path` with that URL, works fine for me with 1.18

Comment: @peeskillet: I was afraid someone would say that :) If this turns out to be an old Jersey bug, I am going to break something.

Comment: Just tested with 1.9 and works also :-(

Comment: @peeskillet: Can you provide your code sample?

Comment: Yes I will post it, but note I just tested with standalone grizzly container, not with tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Per comment to post test (note: using standalone grizzly container, not tomcat)

```
@Path("/email")
public class EmailResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}/{emailAddress : (.+)?}")
    public Response getEmail(@PathParam("id") String id,
                             @PathParam("emailAddress") String email) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("id: ").append(id).append("\n");
        builder.append("email: ").append(email).append("\n");

        return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Standalone server

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {

    private static int getPort(int defaultPort) {
        //grab port from environment, otherwise fall back to default port 9998
        String httpPort = System.getProperty("jersey.test.port");
        if (null != httpPort) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(httpPort);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
        return defaultPort;
    }

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/api").port(getPort(8080)).build();
    }

    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig 
                 = new PackagesResourceConfig("jersey1.stackoverflow.standalone");
        System.out.println("Starting grizzly2...");
        return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, resourceConfig);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Grizzly 2 initialization
        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...",
                BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }    
}
```

Note: the resource class is in `jersey1.stackoverflow.standalone`. To run the server, just run the `Main` class. The resource class will be autodiscovered based on `new PackagesResourceConfig("jersey1.stackoverflow.standalone")`

Using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>       <!-- 1.9 -->
</dependency>
```

Maven archytype can be retreived from

```
Group id: com.sun.jersey.archetypes
Artifact id: jersey-quickstart-grizzly2
Version: 1.9
```

Curl

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/email/5/emailpart1/part2@example.org
```

Result:

```
id: 5
email: emailpart1/part2@example.org
```

Comment: Wow this example works for me, but not the piece I have running with Tomcat. I checked the request and it comes in with the %2F, but it just gives me "The requested URL /../id/email was not found on this server" Not sure where else to look.

Comment: Turns out Apache was blocking it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache