# JAX-RS @Path with allowed slashes collide with other resources

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to allow slashes in my Path:

```
@Path("/user/{login}/points")
```

by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291428/jax-rs-pathparam-how-to-pass-a-string-with-slashes-hyphens-equals-too/23482769) so it becomes:

```
@Path("/user/{login : .+}/points")
```

but it will not work anytime a user names their account e.g

```
test/points
```

because only "**test**" will be passed. It works fine with **test/test** or any other login not ending with /points.

I have no idea how should I solve this. I need it as String param and it's set by user.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in this solution    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291428/jax-rs-pathparam-how-to-pass-a-string-with-slashes-hyphens-equals-too/23482769  it is showing to use (+) symbol why are you using (*) symbol

Comment: @Mahesh, sorry it is a typo really, I have tested it with the plus sign.

Comment: @YCF_L: sadly it includes /points into the results, but I guess it is some kind of solution!

Comment: can you provide method signature.

Comment: What about URL encode the user's login?

Comment: @Mahesh 
public Response getPoints(@PathParam("login") String login) throws ApplicationException

I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the solution myself with a little help of @YCF_L (sadly he deleted his comment).

Solution:

```
@Path("/user/{login : .+(?=\\/points)}")
```